# Save tableView content to NSUserDefaults Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I have table view which displays a list of items. Every time a row is selected, a checkmark is added, a corresponding amount is added to `var total.`

If another row is selected the checkmark of the previous row is removed,the amount for the previous row is subtracted.

I am trying to save and retrieve to/from NSUserdefaults the following info: 
checkmark of the row selected (if any was selected),
 value for `var total`,
indexPathForCellSelected,
,amount for the specific row that was selected.

```
import UIKit
class EighthViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {



struct Item {
    var name:String // name of the row
    var selected:Bool // whether is selected or not
    var amount: Int // value of the item
}

var frequency = [

    Item(name:"Every week",selected: false, amount: 30),
    Item(name:"Every 2 weeks",selected: false, amount: 30),
    Item(name:"Every 4 weeks",selected: false, amount: 30),
    Item(name:"Once",selected: false, amount: 40),
    Item(name:"End of tenancy cleaning", selected: false, amount: 44)
]

var total = 0
var indexPathForCellSelected: NSIndexPath?
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
let indexKey = "indexPathForCellSelected"
let totalKey = "total"
let amountKey = "amount"



override func viewDidLoad() {
        }

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // retrieve indexPathForCellSelected from NSUserDefaults
    if let retrievedIndexPath = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(indexKey) {
        let data1 = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(indexKey) as? NSData
            indexPathForCellSelected = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data1!) as? NSIndexPath

            // retrieve total from NSUserDefaults
            if let totalRetrieved = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(totalKey) as? Int {
        total = totalRetrieved
                print(total)
        }

        //
        if let itemAmount =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(amountKey) as? Int {
            let myIndexpath = indexPathForCellSelected?.row
                frequency[myIndexpath!].amount = itemAmount

             **UPDATED:** tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPathForCellSelected!)?.accessoryType = .Checkmark

        }
    }
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return frequency.count
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

// configure the cell
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    -> UITableViewCell     {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")
        cell?.textLabel?.text = frequency[indexPath.row].name
    return cell!
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if !frequency[indexPath.row].selected {

        // this avoid set initial value for the first time
        if let index = indexPathForCellSelected {
            // clear the previous cell
            frequency[index.row].selected = false
            tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(index)?.accessoryType = .None
            self.total -= frequency[index.row].amount
            print(total)
        }

        // mark the new one
        frequency[indexPath.row].selected = true
        tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.accessoryType = .Checkmark

        indexPathForCellSelected = indexPath
        self.total += frequency[indexPath.row].amount
        print(total)

       if indexPathForCellSelected != nil { // check if there is a selected row in the table

        //save indexPathForCellSelected in NSUserDefaults
     let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(indexPathForCellSelected!)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: indexKey)

            //save total in NSUserDefaults
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(total, forKey: totalKey)

            // save amount in NSUserDefaults
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(frequency[indexPath.row].amount, forKey: amountKey)

        } // end of if indexPathForCellSelected
    }
 }

}
```

here is screenshot from the app : [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u2sw7o1lvkwhbr0/Screenshot%202016-07-19%2017.09.55.png?dl=0)

Comment: @Victor Sigler. Could you please have a look at the code above?

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: @tommybananas  when I select a row instead of adding the amount corresponding to the row selected, it subtracts the amount.

Comment: Why that complicated? it's much easier to save only the index (the row). It's just an integer and property list compliant.

Comment: @vadian   I don't know why It was subtracting the amount (as per link shown above). I have deleted the app, then run the code again and it works properly. I addition, I am assigning the checkmark to the corresponding row using "indexPathForCellSelected". I will update the code.

Comment: I mean, don't save the entire index path, save only `indexPath.row` then you don't need the archive/unarchive dance. You can save integers easily with (`NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey / setInteger: forKey:..`)

Comment: @vadian  I need to save `indexPathForCellSelected` in NSUserDefaults because this is how I keep track of the selected row. I have managed to get the expected result eventually. I have a similar construction and I am struggling to make it work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38484660/error-when-trying-to-save-to-nsuserdefaults        . thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This code works. If anyone has a better implementation, please post it in the answer section.

```
class EighthViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {



struct Item {
    var name:String // name of the row
    var selected:Bool // whether is selected or not
    var amount: Int // value of the item
}

var frequency = [

    Item(name:"Every week",selected: false, amount: 30),
    Item(name:"Every 2 weeks",selected: false, amount: 30),
    Item(name:"Every 4 weeks",selected: false, amount: 30),
    Item(name:"Once",selected: false, amount: 40),
    Item(name:"End of tenancy cleaning", selected: false, amount: 44)
]

var total = 0
var indexPathForCellSelected: NSIndexPath?
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
let indexKey = "indexPathForCellSelected"
let totalKey = "total"
let amountKey = "amount"



override func viewDidLoad() {
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // retrieve indexPathForCellSelected from NSUserDefaults
if let retrievedIndexPath = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dataForKey(indexKey) {
if let data1 = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(retrievedIndexPath) as? NSIndexPath{
    indexPathForCellSelected = data1
}




        // retrieve total from NSUserDefaults
        if let totalRetrieved = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(totalKey) as? Int {
            total = totalRetrieved
            print(total)
        }

        //
      if let itemAmount =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(amountKey) as? Int {
            let myIndexpath = indexPathForCellSelected?.row
            frequency[myIndexpath!].amount = itemAmount

            tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPathForCellSelected!)?.accessoryType = .Checkmark

        }
    }
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return frequency.count
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

// configure the cell
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    -> UITableViewCell     {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")
        cell?.textLabel?.text = frequency[indexPath.row].name
        return cell!
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if !frequency[indexPath.row].selected {

        // this avoid set initial value for the first time
        if let index = indexPathForCellSelected {
            // clear the previous cell
            frequency[index.row].selected = false
                tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(index)?.accessoryType = .None
                    self.total -= frequency[index.row].amount
                        print(total)
        }

        // mark the new one
        frequency[indexPath.row].selected = true
            tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.accessoryType = .Checkmark
                self.total += frequency[indexPath.row].amount
                    indexPathForCellSelected = indexPath
        print(total)

        if indexPathForCellSelected != nil { // check if there is a selected row in the table

            //save indexPathForCellSelected in NSUserDefaults
            let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(indexPathForCellSelected!)
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: indexKey)

            //save total in NSUserDefaults
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(total, forKey: totalKey)

            // save amount in NSUserDefaults
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(frequency[indexPath.row].amount, forKey: amountKey)

        } // end of if indexPathForCellSelected
    }
  }

}
```